# What does "spark plugs appear yellow at the ignition point" mean?

Tags: piston-engine, ignition

I was reading the [DLE-120 engine User Manual](https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/673073/dle-120.html?page=4) and saw this paragraph:

> **Caution:** Running the engine with a lean fuel mixture will cause the engine to overheat and burn the electrode of the spark plugs. Pay close attention to the High-speed Needle adjustment. Running the engine with the proper fuel mixture will make the spark plugs appear yellow at the ignition point.

What does "yellow" mean in "Running the engine with the proper fuel mixture will make the spark plugs appear ***yellow*** at the ignition point"?

Does anybody have any experience or images of this phenomenon?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Use the tip residue to evaluate the combustion process

The *yellow* the manual is describing is the normal condition found in the top left corner:

[image]

If the plug is not the yellow/tan shown in the top left, then it will almost certainly look like one of the other pictures. This is a strong hint that what is going on inside the cylinder is not optimal, and points in the direction of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. another question: Is this colors valid for piston engines which use fuel+oil or it is valid for piston engine that use just fuel like car engines?

Comment: AFAIK, it is valid for both. Be aware that some of the remedies make less sense for a fuel/oil mixture, though (such as checking piston rings for blow-by due to oil fouling on the plugs).